# Use Url Argument in contextual filter for Block View

Tags: views

I have a View which uses contextual Filter to compare my URL last Argument with Taxonomy term. This Works when my view is Page but doesn't work in block mode. This is my View Below.
[image: This is my View]

Attaching my view and Site Description along this.
My Pdf Category View is placed as a block. 
[image]
When I Preview by entering the brand name emax in the view, it give me proper results but it doesn't fetch from url(RAW Value from URL). Correct me if i failed to mention anything wrong.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution for this issue. I used PHP code by selecting "Provide Default" and Select PHP code as below to extract arguments from URL and provide a filter to your view.

```
$path = drupal_get_path_alias();
$path = explode("/", $path);
return $path[2] /* Since explode function return array of url arguments, select required arguments starting with 0.*/
```